# Need to run a SUBSTRING_INDEX inside of a SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql

I have a LOAD DATA mysql query im trying to run and need help to fix one thing.

Here is the query im running

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file_app' 
    INTO TABLE tbl_user_tmp 
    LINES STARTING BY '{' 
    TERMINATED BY '/>' 
    (@name) 
    set 
    name=SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'\"',-2),
    activity=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'}',1),'/',1),
    class=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'}',1),'/',-1),
    user = '$user'" ;
```

Here is the example of data from file im trying to load.

```
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.apps.aaa.roadside/com.apps.aaa.roadside.Splash}" drawable="aaa_roadside1" />
```

With the above query i get the following

```
name=aaa_roadside1" 
activity=com.apps.aaa.roadside
class=com.apps.aaa.roadside.Splash
```

Everything is correct but name. I need to removed that last "

I thought the below query would work but it does not. any ideas?

This was working before when i had TERMINATED BY set to this '\" />'
However this will not account for entires that might not have that space at end like this

```
<item component="ComponentInfo{com.apps.aaa.roadside/com.apps.aaa.roadside.Splash}" drawable="aaa_roadside1"/>
```

I need to account for both

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file_app' 
INTO TABLE tbl_user_tmp 
LINES STARTING BY '{' 
TERMINATED BY '/>' 
(@name) 
set 
name=SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'\"',-2),-1),
activity=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'}',1),'/',1),
class=SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@name,'}',1),'/',-1),
user = '$user'" ;
```

Comment: Have you considered using [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-xml.html) instead?

Comment: Yes, but didn't seem to work either. Maybe i wasn't doing it right?